# NS-3: module errors while building

Tags: simulator, ns-3

I have problem in newest ns-3.26 with nsc-0.5.3 and gccxml-ns3 - system is very up-to-date so that's not the case.

> Building nsc-0.5.3 - Problem
>
> Problem: Optional dependency, module "nsc-0.5.3" failed
>
> This may reduce the functionality of the final build. However, bake will continue since "nsc-0.5.3" is not an essential dependency. For more information call bake with -v or -vvv, for full verbose mode.

Comment: The recommended Forum for asking ns3 questions is https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-3-users , where the ns3 developers also will answer questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the solution** - NSC doesn't work properly with gcc/g++-6 so I had to change default version of gcc and g++ (for example from 6.3.0 to 5.4.1)

1) Find installed compilers:

```
dpkg --list | grep compiler
```

2) Change default gcc, g++, cc and c++ (via https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 20

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 20

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc 30
sudo update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/g++ 30
sudo update-alternatives --set c++ /usr/bin/g++
```

Also, to check if changes are saved:

```
gcc -v
```

It should say: "gcc version 5.4.1" at the end.

After that, NSC was installed successfully.

It's worth mentioning that it didn't fix gccxml's problem, but in my case I needed NSC working so...